# Text to Date conversion

Tags: formula-field, administration

I want to convert text value into date .
Text field contain value= 21-FEB-2022

DATE() function is not working as value is not in proper format

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to translate the month into a number:

```
DATE(
  VALUE(RIGHT(Field__c, 4)), // year
  CASE(MID(Field__c, 3, 3), 
    'JAN',1,'FEB',2,'MAR',3,'APR',4,'MAY',5,'JUN',6,
    'JUL',7,'AUG',8,'SEP',9,'OCT',10,'NOV',11,12),
  VALUE(LEFT(Field__c,2)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use  DATEVALUE() to convert into Date.
It returns a date value for a date/time or text expression.

Refer this link : [Convert to Date Format](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm)

Comment: This would require the text to be "2022-02-21" instead of "21-FEB-2022".